# Accessing visual studio android emulator files

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

I need to get access to the android files from the VS xde android emulator, at least to a sqlite DB created in the same app directory.

Anyway to access those files?

Answer (score 2):

I just found this trick seems to work.

1. Open Hyper-V manager
2. Double click the virtual machine
3. On the shell, run as admin using su
4. Do whatever you want in the shell!

I can inspect any text file using the cat command

I can also copy it to the /sdcard directory, and then I can access it with astro file manager or DropBox. You can install those apps by just downloading the APK and drag into the emulator.